# Is there a portable (non-su) file sync application for linux?

Tags: linux, sync, portable

On my own machine, I use [unison](http://www.cis.upenn.edu/~bcpierce/unison/), but I need a different solution for my machine @work.
I have no superuser permissions and dropbox et al. are blacklisted.

The only thing I can use is a USB stick. Which is a pain to use for large workspace sync without a proper tool. The only portable version of unison I was able to find is windows-only, so I'm lost.

Is there a portable sync app for linux (RHEL 5.5)? Maybe sth. in python (got 2.4 installed)?

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[rsync](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rsync) should be installed out of the box on unison.

Comment: It is. As a recovering windows user I have never used it though, and my command-line-fu is weak. So I'm  reading a tutorial on rsync right now. Thank you

Comment: Worked fine with -avz --delete settings. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You probably already have GTK2 installed, so both `unison` and `unison-gtk2` should run fine as long as they are linked to the same library version (command-line `unison` only depends on glibc, so it should work practically everywhere). The Unison [`.rpm` packages](http://pkgs.repoforge.org/unison/) can be extracted manually with `rpmextract` or `cpio`, on your home machine, then copied over.